# Will this refactoring of a condition combining boolean and comparison operators work?

Tags: python, conditional-statements

I'm trying to set the following conditions:

```
if N < W or N < S:
    if E < W or E < S:
        # code to be executed
```

I came across something which I believe could qualify as a more shorthand version of the above, which I haven't seen before and was advised against:

```
if (N and E) < (E or S):
    # code to be executed
```

Is the latter expression of the conditions OK? Will it function as intended by the first expression?

Comment: I have no idea how that second form could possibly work. Remember what `and` and `or` do *prior* to the evaluation of `<`. You were "advised against" this because it's not logical, it's just a bunch of conditions jumbled together.

Comment: No, that won't work. The two sides of the `<` operator are evaluated first, with the *results* compared to each other with `<`. You can't factor the expression like this.

Comment: You *could* write `if not (W <= N >= S):` (using De Morgan's Laws and comparison chaining), but I would not recommend it.

Comment: `N < W or N < S` is the same as `N < max(W, S)`. Likewise, `E < max(W, S)`. Now instead of a nested ifs we can go with a single condition `N < max(W, S) and E < max(W, S)`, which in turn can be simplified further to `max(N, E) < max(W, S)`...

Answer (score 1):

This will not work. There is no "distribution" of comparison operators and the Boolean operators analogous to the distribution of multiplication over addition.

```
if (N and E) < (E or S):
```

is equivalent to

```
t1 = N and E  # N if N is false, otherwise E
t2 = E or S  # E if E is true, S otherwise
if t1 < t2:
    ...
```

Only one comparison with `<` is made, not a set of comparisons based on some presumed distribution of `<` over `and` and `or`.

Further, whether or how you can collapse a nested `if` statement into a single statement with a compound condition depends on the whole statement. For example,

```
if condition1:
    if condition2:
        do_thing_1
```

is equivalent to

```
if condition1 and condition2:
    do_thing_1
```

but

```
if condition1:
    if condition2:
        do_thing_1
    else:
        do_thing_2
```

is equivalent to

```
if condition1 and condition2:
    do_thing_1
elif condition1:
    do_thing_2
```

(and even then, only if `condition1` has no side effects, allowing you to evaluate it a second time without changing the meaning of your code.)